# Notify when application comes to foreground

Tags: android, notify, foreground

I have a service which has to monitor which application is in the foreground and based on the application do some functionality.

I can get the list of foreground applications, using ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().
But with this I cannot monitor when the foreground application changes.

ex. when Application 1 which was foreground goes to background and a new Application 2 comes to foreground, the service should be notified about this.

Are there any Broadcasting happening in Android, so that my service can register to that and when there is a change in foreground application, the service gets a notification and can do the functionality as required.

I do not want to do any changes in the Applications...
Any possibilities please suggest...

Comment: Hey, did u have any luck to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Then a simple solution is Create static variable of type `Context()` in some Class and in all `onResume()` methods activities initialize  it with their Instances.. and check it in service using `if conditon` and carry on..

Comment: yeah this is a simple solution...but I do not want to modify the application code...I want my service to get a notification when any application comes to foreground...
my service should be able to monitor all applications (default and newly created) applications...