# How to check if Android app came back to foreground?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have to know when my app comes back to the foreground in these situations:

- Start app
- Start Activity A
- Home Pressed
- App brought to foreground by user. (Activity A is shown)
- Start app
- Start Activity A
- Start Activity B
- Home Pressed
- App brought to foreground by user. (Activity B is shown)

I cannot check this with a flag in `onResume` and `onPause`. Because this would trigger every time `Activity B` is loaded.

Comment: Please check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489993/check-android-application-is-in-foreground-or-not

Comment: If I understand that answer can check if the app is in foreground. Not if it came back to the foreground.

Comment: How about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385620/notify-when-application-comes-to-foreground

Comment: Also not. The problem in most answers on related questions is that they set something in onResume and remove it in onPause. This does not work because this will also trigger if an Activity is loaded from an other Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work but try overriding the `onUserLeaveHint` of your `Activity`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()

If this one is called, set a boolean field of your `Activity` to true. When the `onResume` is called, check for this boolean. If it is true, then your `Activity` is coming back into the foreground (don't forget to set this boolean back to false again).

BTW: I like your KlaasVaak handle :). Are your trying to make people sleepy :)

Comment: It works in case the user presses the home button but the condition is also triggered when the user just switches to another app and then back. Only Klaasvaak can answer whether that would meet his requirements or not ;-)

Comment: onUserLeaveHint is also called when an activity is started for result. For example the camera. So this would trigger the coming back to background. I do not see this as coming back from the background.